# bootstrap navigation bar dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am making a navigation bar for my website but it doesn't seem to work.
When I click on the products tab which I have made a dropdown menu it works like a dead link and takes me to index.php# . Please Help. I am attaching the markup for it :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php" >HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>


            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PRODUCTS <span class="caret"></span></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="boys.php">BOYS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="girls.php">GIRLS</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>    
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you included links from bootstrap

```
and add jquery and script at bottom wid jquery above javascript
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">




<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes I have done all that. When i test the code separately it works but it doesn't work when i use it in my website. I literally copy pasted it but still it doesn't work there.

Comment: can you post your whole html page

Comment: <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">    <!--add this above ul and </div> after ul is over-->

Comment: you must have included cdn of bootstrap i cant see that

Comment: I have included in the head.php file . Here it is:

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Final Site</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: add script at the end of body

Comment: till now your script does not know that navbar class is defined

Comment: and add jquery too it sometimes required and accept my answer if it worked out

Comment: thanks it worked after i added your code. Can you tell me what was missing as i had included the links given on the bootstrap site.

Comment: you should include javascript at end and add link for jquery as bootstrap also uses jquery

Comment: this problem also occurs for me then i have FAQ of bootstrap and got answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
        <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.php" >HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>


                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PRODUCTS <span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="boys.php">BOYS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="girls.php">GIRLS</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </nav>



<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: whats the problem now

Comment: if you have question ask i will try to answer

Comment: sorry but i am unknown to deployment of pages and will not able to debug